# twitter4j and singpost lib in android 4.0 and further

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

Can someone give me a tutorial about using twitter4j in android 4.0 and further?

I was able to use twitter4j before but now I cant, it keeps throwing this error:

"oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null"

I found in web that the problem is that you can't access the network on the IU Thread anymore... And I tried but I cant fix the problem.

So I want to know how to implemment twitter in android again. Any tutorial??

Thanks!